# How to pass a value from within a List up to a method? MessagingCenter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I have created a List object for charting in SyncFusion. I have performed a calculation at the end of the List creation that gets the Minimum value of one of the objects in the List (which is 'close'), and ascribes it to a variable called 'AxisMinimum'. That works fine.

I now need to take that variable's value and pass it up into another method that can then use it and make an adjustment to the chart. That method is called 'NumbericalAxis_ActualRangeChanged'.

Trying to use AxisMinimum in the 'NumbericalAxis_ActualRangeChanged' method generates an error as it doesn't exist in the current context. Would using a Messaging.Center approach be appropriate or is there a better way?

```
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NumericalAxis_ActualRangeChanged(object sender, ActualRangeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ActualMinimum = AxisMinimum;
    }
}


public class SaleInfo
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string minute { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double open { get; set; }
    public double close { get; set; }
    public double average { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
    public double notional { get; set; }
    public int numberOfTrades { get; set; }
}

public class SalesViewModel
{
    public List<SaleInfo> SalesData { get; set; }

    public SalesViewModel()
    {
        SalesData = new List<SaleInfo>();

        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { date = "2019-08-16", minute = "09:30", label = "09:30 AM", high = 204.84, low = 204.05, open = 204.3, close = 904.75, average = 204.508, volume = 8709, notional = 1781061.51, numberOfTrades = 69 });
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { date = "2019-08-16", minute = "09:31", label = "09:31 AM", high = 204.8, low = 204.46, open = 204.8, close = 904.5, average = 204.622, volume = 5783, notional = 1183329.75, numberOfTrades = 58 });
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { date = "2019-08-16", minute = "09:32", label = "09:32 AM", high = 204.72, low = 204.34, open = 204.46, close = 904.36, average = 204.548, volume = 4468, notional = 913920.6, numberOfTrades = 50 });
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { date = "2019-08-16", minute = "09:33", label = "09:33 AM", high = 204.41, low = 204.06, open = 204.39, close = 904.06, average = 204.243, volume = 1834, notional = 374581.99, numberOfTrades = 22 });

        double AxisMinimum = SalesData.Min(SaleInfo => SaleInfo.close);
    }
}
```

Comment: just define AxisMinimum as a public property on your VM, then you can reference it from other classes

Comment: Use the messaging center, your vm shouldn't directly talk with each other as in other viewmodels. It's provided for a great reason; to allow publishers to send messages without having knowledge of any receivers and vice versus.

Comment: Hi Jason, if I define AxisMinimum as public in the VM, then go up to the NumericalAxis_ActualRangeChanged method, AxisMinimum generates an error that it does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Çöđěxěŕ, that did the trick. Using the following code made it work...

```
    public void NumericalAxis_ActualRangeChanged(object sender, ActualRangeChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                SalesViewModel p = new SalesViewModel();
                e.ActualMinimum = p.AxisMinimum;
             }
```

By creating an instance of SalesViewModel object I could then get at that variable and use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the above solution, doesn't provide you with the correct value of AxisMinium (min value of Close property values in SaleInfo). Because each time, you are creating a new instance of SalesViewModel.

`SalesViewModel p = new SalesViewModel();`

It has been modified by

```
public void NumericalAxis_ActualRangeChanged(object sender,ActualRangeChangedEventArgs e){

SalesViewModel p = (sender as Axis).BindingContext as SalesViewModel;   
if(p != null )
{                   
  e.ActualMinimum = p.AxisMinimum;
}}
```